# Angular Reload D3 Chart Directive after event

Tags: angularjs, d3.js

I am trying to get a angular directive element which creates a d3 chart (similar to those seen here http://phloxblog.in/angulard3/start.html#.Vd5w_bM2w_t) to change its data source after an event occurs.

Currently I have the directive working properly with a static data source, but I need to be able to react to user-defined events that cause a data fetch from API and reload the chart. In effect I want something like this:

```
<myDirective dataSource={{some $scope variable here}} otherStuff=... />
```

But this does not seem to work, as the $scope variable does not get evaluated.

Another alternative that I think could work is having the directive do something like this:

```
<myDirective ng-model="some $scope variable here" />
```

so that the directive has access to 1 $scope level variable which is a json object with my configs.

Sorry if this is a basic question. I have tried figuring out how to do this, but I am not entirely sure what I need to google in Angular terms.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can watch the variables which get changes when there is a some user defined events.

```
$scope.$watch (function ($scope) {
   // Lets $scope.variable be the variable which gets changed 
   // when there is a user event
    return $scope.variable
}, function () {
     //perform your data fetch from API here
     // load it into the data source
});
```

The above code has to be in your controller.

A good tutorial on $scope.watch() is provided at [here](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2658-using-scope-watch-to-watch-functions-in-angularjs.htm).